# Biblatex: Filter out cloned entry from bibliography iff source entry also appears

Tags: biblatex

In my custom biblatex style, I have some bibliography entries that use the related field in such a way that the related entry should appear in the bibliography. This is achieved by setting `relatedoptions = {dataonly,skipbib=false}`.

It is also possible for the related entry to be cited directly in the same document.

In this case, the entry will appear *twice* in the bibliography: once for the actual entry and once for the cloned entry created by the `related` field.

How can I filter out one of these duplicate entries *without* the end-user having to worry about what they cite and make manual adjustments?

In the following MWE, the list of references in both sections should be the same (matching the **Cite b only** list of references):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author = {Name, A. N.},
  title = {A Book}
}
@book{b,
  author = {Name, Another},
  title = {A Different Book},
  related = {a},
  relatedstring = {Related Book:},
  relatedoptions = {dataonly,skipbib=false}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\section*{Cite a and b}
\cite{a}\par\cite{b}
\printbibliography
\vspace{1cm}
\section*{Cite b only}
\newrefsection
\cite{b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this a `biber` bug which is fixed in 2.6 DEV (which I can't currently upload but will update here when done). I think `skipbib/skipbiblist` should always be forced on a related clone if a related clone is also directly cited.

Comment: PLK, you're a champ! I've never known a developer to be so willing and quick to add features and fix things. Works perfectly with my MWE above.

Comment: Actually, this has introduced a regression. I'll open an issue on github.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/123

Comment: Please try now, also 2.6 DEV binaries are uploaded with the fix. Regression tests are in place for this too now.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. Always answering my own questions.

Here's a way that works. I can use `\defbibcheck` to check cloned entries against real entries. It's easy to make this check happen by default by redefining `\printbibliography`. It needs something similar to work with the list of shorthands.

Any better suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author = {Name, A. N.},
  title = {A Book}
}
@book{b,
  author = {Name, Another},
  title = {A Different Book},
  related = {a},
  relatedstring = {Related Book:},
  relatedoptions = {dataonly,skipbib=false}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\defbibcheck{uniqueclones}{%
  \iffieldundef{clonesourcekey}
    {\ifcsdef{sbl@entrykey@\therefsection\strfield{entrykey}}
       {\skipentry}
       {\savefieldcs{entrykey}{sbl@entrykey@\therefsection\strfield{entrykey}}}}
    {\ifcsdef{sbl@entrykey@\therefsection\strfield{clonesourcekey}}
       {\skipentry}
       {\savefieldcs{clonesourcekey}{sbl@entrykey@\therefsection\strfield{clonesourcekey}}}}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Cite a and b}
\cite{a}\par\cite{b}
\printbibliography[check=uniqueclones]
\vspace{1cm}
\section*{Cite b only}
\newrefsection
\cite{b}
\printbibliography[check=uniqueclones]
\end{document}
```

Comment: *"Sigh. Always answering my own questions."* Sure, but without the question there just would be no answer :-) I have experienced this myself a couple of times: Stating the question, carefully crafting the MWE, and so on appears to start some background process in your brain that – sometimes – brings up the answer. Thanks for sharing it with us!